# Scraping AJAX page with requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the results of [this booking flow](https://shop.caremar.it/it/ticket_s1).

By looking at the network tab I've found out that the data is retrieved with an AJIAX GET at this URL:

```
https://shop.caremar.it/main_acquista_1_corse_00_ajax.asp?l=it&data=24/02/2019&portoP=3&portoA=5&form_url=ticket_s1_2
```

I've build the URL passing the parameters as follows:

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'data': '24/02/2019',
        'portoP': '3' ,
        'portoA': '5',
        'form_url': 'ticket_s1_2',
    })
```

and make the request:

```
caremar_timetable_url = "https://shop.caremar.it/main_acquista_1_corse_00_ajax.asp?l=it&"
print(f"https://shop.caremar.it/main_acquista_1_corse_00_ajax.asp?l=it&{params}")
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.3'}
res = requests.get(caremar_timetable_url,headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
print(soup.text)
```

Output

```
https://shop.caremar.it/main_acquista_1_corse_00_ajax.asp?l=it&data=24%2F02%2F2019&portoP=7&portoA=1&form_url=ticket_s1_2
Non Ã¨ stato possibile procedere con l'acquisto del biglietto online. Si prega di riprovare
```

The response is an error message from the site which says it can't complete the booking. If I copy and paste  the URL I  created in the browser I get an unstyled HTML page with the data I need.
Why is this and how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data seems to come back with requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'https://shop.caremar.it/main_acquista_1_corse_00_ajax.asp?l=it&data=27/02/2019&portoP=1&portoA=4&form_url=ticket_s1_2'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('html'))
```

Comment: though this might be just the search part so feedback would be useful.

Comment: Hey QHarr, thanks for the help- it helped me troubleshoot my issue. It was passing the date as a parameter causing the issue. I've added the date as a string to the URL and then passed the remaining parameters and it worked.